# Radeon: Invalid ROM contents

Tags: dual-boot, radeon, upstart

I have a dual-boot Windows - Ubuntu 16.04 desktop computer with a Radeon HD 7950 graphics card. Yesterday I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Everything seemed to be OK. I started Ubuntu a couple of times just to check that everything is working normally. However, when I tried to start Ubuntu today I got this message on a black text-mode screen:

```
[     1.180337] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Pressing Control-D nevertheless doesn't help, it just causes the message to reappear. Neither helps #systemctl default.
But Ubuntu does start almost normally in upstart mode (right now I'm writing this from Ubuntu running in this mode).

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple workaround.

The problem only appears if I turn off the computer from Windows and start Ubuntu on the next power-on. Then we got into that "Invalid ROM contents" message. If that happened, it's enough to first start Windows and restart the computer from Windows. Ubuntu starts without problems after that.

Since I encountered this problem, I added an SSD into the computer, reinstalled Windows once again, moved Ubuntu to the SSD, changed the monitor (the old one was connected through DVI, the new one through Display Port). None of this affected the problem. It's still easily reproduced on my computer. Steps are simple: start Windows, turn off the computer from Windows, turn on the computer and try to start Ubuntu.